# Console.log only showing for a split second

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Has anyone ever came across this problem? I have stripped my app down completely to basically a shell in a new React app so it's only the layout and a console.log on a button click

```html
  return (
    <div className='mainDiv'>
      <form className='inputDiv'>
        <div className='dayDiv'>
          <label htmlFor='day'>DAY</label>
          <input type='number' placeholder='DD' name='day' id='day' min='1' max='31' ></input>
        </div>
        <div className='monthDiv'>
          <label htmlFor='month'>MONTH</label>
          <input type='number' placeholder='MM' name='month' id='month' min='01' max='12'></input>
        </div>
        <div className='yearDiv'>
          <label htmlFor='year'>YEAR</label>
          <input type='number' placeholder='YYYY' name='year' id='year' min='1900' max='2023'></input>
        </div>
        <div className='lineDiv'>
          <div className='lineBtn'>
            <div className='break' />
            <button className='btn' onClick={() => console.log('hello')}>
              <img src='./images/logo2.png' className='btnImg' alt='logo' />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div className='dataDiv'>
        <p>
          <span className='spanNumbers'>--</span>
          <span className='spanText'>years</span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <span className='spanNumbers'>--</span>
          <span className='spanText'>months</span>
        </p><p>
          <span className='spanNumbers'>--</span>
          <span className='spanText'>days</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I click the button, it shows up in my chrome console saying 'hello' for about half a second, then it looks like the console refreshes and it's gone

I read about similar problems where it was an extension but I have deleted all my extensions and it still doesn't work, I'm not getting any errors show up on the chrome console or in my vscode console so I am really struggling to troubleshoot this

Comment: Is the *page* reloading?  That often clears the console.  I know the Network tab can persist across multiple page loads, not sure if there's an option for that in the console.

Comment: Your `<button>` by default will submit the containing form. Add `type=button` to the `<button>` tag.

Comment: Set the button type="button". By default it is of type="submit" that refreshes the page and considers it a form submission. Another way is to use event.preventDefault() to prevent the default actions from submit button.

Comment: thank you pointy, that seems to have solved it. I'm still learning HTML/React and it's quite a steep learning curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `button` is inside the `form` component, so that button by default will be `type='submit'`.

You need to set it as `type='button'` to prevent the form submit

```html
    <div className='mainDiv'>
      <form className='inputDiv'>
        <div className='dayDiv'>
          <label htmlFor='day'>DAY</label>
          <input type='number' placeholder='DD' name='day' id='day' min='1' max='31' ></input>
        </div>
        <div className='monthDiv'>
          <label htmlFor='month'>MONTH</label>
          <input type='number' placeholder='MM' name='month' id='month' min='01' max='12'></input>
        </div>
        <div className='yearDiv'>
          <label htmlFor='year'>YEAR</label>
          <input type='number' placeholder='YYYY' name='year' id='year' min='1900' max='2023'></input>
        </div>
        <button className='btn' type="button" onClick={console.log('hello')}>
          hello
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
```